# Is there a Kotlin-coroutine-friendly way to do transactions with jOOQ?

Tags: kotlin, jooq

Sometimes we want to have a suspend function that calls other suspend functions inside of a transaction:

```kotlin
suspend fun mySuspendFunction(jooqContext: DSLContext) {
    jooqContext.transaction { config ->
        val transactionContext: DSLContext = config.dsl()

        // ... some code that uses transactionContext ...
        anotherSuspendFunction(transactionContext)
        // ... more code that uses transactionContext ...
    }
}
```

However, this won't compile, because jOOQ's `DSLContext.transaction` takes a non-suspending function as its parameter, and so the body of the transaction cannot call a suspend function directly. The above will fail to compile with an error like:

> Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body

One workaround is to use `runBlocking` around the suspend calls:

```kotlin
suspend fun mySuspendFunction(jooqContext: DSLContext) {
    jooqContext.transaction { config ->
        val transactionContext: DSLContext = config.dsl()

        // ... some code that uses transactionContext ...
        runBlocking {
            anotherSuspendFunction(transactionContext)
        }
        // ... more code that uses transactionContext ...
    }
}
```

However [the documentation for `runBlocking`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) advises against using it in this way ("designed to bridge regular blocking code to libraries that are written in suspending style, **to be used in main functions and in tests**").

That's just a hint of the real problem, which is that because `DSLContext.transaction` is calling a non-suspend function for the transaction body, the coroutine's thread is blocking (ie: cannot suspend) for the duration of the transaction.

I thought about making a suspend-friendly transaction wrapper for Kotlin,
[but jOOQ does not yet have a procedural transaction API](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5376). Also, `DSLContext.connection` blocks on the supplied function so I don't see a way to get a hold of the single `Connection` for the duration of the transaction without blocking.

Is there a way to use a jOOQ transaction in a Kotlin coroutine that does not block for the duration of the transaction, and which allows suspend functions to be called from within the transaction body?

Answer (score 3):

#### jOOQ 3.16

jOOQ 3.16 does not yet have a reactive transaction API. This will be addressed with jOOQ 3.17, soon: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13502

#### jOOQ 3.17 bridging between reactive and coroutines manually

With jOOQ 3.17, you can write:

```kotlin
suspend fun mySuspendFunction(jooqContext: DSLContext): Any {
    return jooqContext.transactionPublisher { config ->

        // Turn the suspension result into a Mono, which implements the reactive
        // streams Publisher<T> SPI, which jOOQ expects as a result from a 
        // TransactionalPublishable
        mono {
            anotherSuspendFunction(config)
        }
    }

    // Turn the Publisher<T> that is returned from transactionPublisher() back 
    // into a suspension result
    .awaitFirst()
}
```

This is assuming, you're using the recommended reactive streams / coroutines bridges:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-core</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlinx.coroutines.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-reactor</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlinx.coroutines.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

#### jOOQ 3.17, alternatively, using `jooq-kotlin-coroutines`

With https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9335, there will be a new module `jooq-kotlin-coroutines`, which you can pull in to bridge between the worlds for you, e.g.

```kotlin
suspend fun mySuspendFunction(jooqContext: DSLContext) {
    jooqContext.transactionCoroutine { config ->
        anotherSuspendFunction(config)
    }
}
```

This just removes the glue code for you

#### jOOQ transaction APIs are just convenience. You don't *need* them

Notice that you don't *need* jOOQ's transaction API, nor do you *need* it to be "procedural." All of this API is just convenience on top of JDBC or R2DBC. You can always access your R2DBC `Connection` directly, and invoke its transaction API directly to achieve non-blocking transactional behaviour. It's just a bit more glue code.

Comment: Regarding the last bit, "... invoke its transaction API directly to achieve non-blocking transactional behaviour." If all I've got is a `DSLContext` in `myFunction`, is there a way to get a JDBC `Connection` from it, or do I need to pass (a way to get) one down separately to everything that might need to do a transaction?

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves: The JDBC `Connection` can be accessed using `DSLContext::connection`, though why use JDBC here, which would again be blocking? I must have still been missing the point so far, assuming that R2DBC was going to be preferred here to get non-blocking behaviour...

Comment: `DSLContext::connection` doesn't return the `Connection`. It takes a `ConnectionRunnable`, effectively a blocking function, so how can it be used to have a transaction that can suspend part way through? This looks like the same problem as `DSLContext::transaction`.

Comment: Regarding R2DBC vs JDBC, yes, eventually I'd like us to switch to it, but I'm not confident it's ready for production use yet.

In the meantime, blocking only for individual statements seems like an ok trade-off, but blocking for the entire duration of a transaction seems needlessly worse.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves, alright then, just do something like `jooqContext.connection { c -> c.commit() }` or `jooqContext.connection { c -> c.rollback() }`. Beware that this runs through the `ConnectionProvider` lifecycle, so you must ensure that your transactional scope will continue receiving the same JDBC `Connection` instance...

Comment: The "beware" is exactly why I don't see how that approach is feasible. How would you ensure that once you begin the transaction, no other coroutine will use your connection, and the transactions's coroutine continues getting the same connection?

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves: The comment section isn't too good for this. Can you please ask a new question? My answer here recommends using R2DBC, and doing what you're doing isn't what I'd recommend. But I can still elaborate in a follow-up question

Answer (score 0):

I will write about the way I know how to do it without using the `API` provided by `jOOQ`.

Here is how to make the `Transactional` annotation work with an `R2DBC` connection.
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12218#issuecomment-1213929029

You can also use `TransactionalOperator` to perform transactions manually if you use `jOOQ` with a connection that `Spring` manages transactions in the way described above.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.reactor.awaitSingle
import kotlinx.coroutines.reactor.mono
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.transaction.reactive.TransactionalOperator

@Component
class TransactionOperation(private val transactionalOperator: TransactionalOperator) {
    suspend operator fun <T> invoke(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): T = transactionalOperator
        .transactional(mono(block = block))
        .awaitSingle()
}

@Component
class Foo(private val transactionOperation: TransactionOperation) {
    suspend fun saveByJooq(entity: Any): Any { TODO("Saving process here.") }

    suspend fun call() {
        // call saving process with transaction.
        transactionOperation { saveByJooq("foo") }
    }
}
```